# Решение примеров в веб приложении

Tags: java, apache, servlet, tomcat

Помогите разобраться! Только начал изучать Java EE, хочу написать что то типа онлайн калькулятора, есть некоторые мысли, но конкретной реализации не могу придумать.

**Что нужно:** на сайте вводится значение переменных a и b, на сервлете подсчитывается сумма a + b и результат выводится на сайт.

Помогите реализовать, или объясните как это можно сделать, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать веб приложение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Web Calculator</h2>
    <form action="calculate" method="get">
        <input type="number" name="a" value="2" /><br>
        <input type="number" name="b" value="3" /><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.jspx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
    </jsp:text>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <c:out value="${result}"/>
    </body>
    </html>

</jsp:root>
```

Calculator.java:

```
package ua.training.model;

public class Calculator {

    public int add(int first, int second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

Controller.java (он же серслет):

```
package ua.training.controller;

import ua.training.model.Calculator;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controller
 */
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Controller() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a"));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));
        int res = calculator.add(a, b);
        request.setAttribute("result", res);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/result.jspx").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

web.xml (на всякий случай):

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ua.training.controller.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/calculate</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```